# ENVIAR RESULTADO DE UNA VARIABLE POR MEDIO DE PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post

Hola que tal compañer@s

Tengo una consulta ya que hice una consulta para que me mostrara una lista en un option  hasta voy bien el detalle que el resultado de ese option lo quiero enviar por metodo post el detalle que al enviar el string por metodo post no me pasa el resultado .
Como podria obtener ese valor y enviarlo , les agradezco mucho su apoyo"!

```
     <form class="form text-dark" method="post" action="ss.php">
         <div class="form-row" style="padding:2%; margin:auto; text-align:center;">
        <select name="marca"   required class="form-control">
            
        <option  value="" class="form-control">-Seleccione Marca-</option> 
    <?php 
    $sql="SELECT * from marcac";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    while($mostrar= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    
 ?>    
  
         <option  value="<?php  $mostrar; ?>"><?php   echo $mostrar['NOMBREM']; ?></option>  
                        <?php 
}
 ?> 
        </select>
```

Generar Consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. Tu variable `$mostrar` es toda la fila, así como tienes `echo $mostrar['NOMBREM']` para la descripción igual debe ser en `value="<?php  $mostrar['idMarcaC']; ?>"`  (`idMarcaC` es de ejemplo; verifica en tu tabla la **PK**).

Comment: listo muchas gracias ! me faltaba el name para que lo enviara gracias!